# PL/SQL converting special characters

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm creating a simple XML 1.0 file with the help of a short PL/SQL function filled with data from a table.

The data from the table contains also HTML characters like <>, & and so on.
For these special characters I've build a short search and replace function which looks like this:

```
 newXmlString := REPLACE(xmlString,    '&',  '&amp;' );
 newXmlString := REPLACE(newXmlString, '\',  '' );
 newXmlString := REPLACE(newXmlString, '<',  '&lt;' );
 newXmlString := REPLACE(newXmlString, '>',  '&gt;' );
 newXmlString := REPLACE(newXmlString, '"',  '&quot;' );
 newXmlString := REPLACE(newXmlString, '''', '&apos;' );
```

Now there is more data in the table which has the effect that the XML file is not able to validate because of special control characters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) like:

- ETX (End of Text)
- SYN (Synchronous Idle)

Note: Not every control character corrupts the validation of a XML file! Linebreaks or Carriage Return is still possible.

Of course I now can search and replace them as well, for example with:

```
newXmlString := REPLACE(newXmlString, chr(3), '' ); -- ETX end of text
```

But is there a build in function or something like a library I can use with PL/SQL without listing and search+replacing them?

**UPDATE 1**

I also tried to use the function `dbms_xmlgen.getxml` but this function throws an error because of 'special char to escaped char conversion failed.'+

**UPDATE 2**

I tried using `REGEXP_REPLACE(STRING_VALUE,'[[:cntrl:]]')` which will work, but this will also delete line breaks, which we want to keep and also has no effect on the validation of a XML file.

Comment: I think `dbms_xmlgen.convert()` is what you are looking for

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: this will convert the html chars but also not the control characters like 'SYN'

Comment: But using that you don't need to take care of all the HTML characters, only the control characters.

Comment: Can you use TRANSLATE (rather than replace), and build up a list of control / html characters to put in the 'string_to_replace'? That should make it tidier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRANSLATE is indeed the way to go. Build a string with the CHR function and apply it only once.
Here is an example for ETX: 3, EOT: 4 and SYN: 22. You can append others when needed.

Notice the 'a' at the start of the string that returns as the only character in the second string. 
This function needs one chracter that is not eliminated.

```
FUNCTION clean_control( in_text IN VARCHAR2 )
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   v_search  VARCHAR2( 30 ) := 'a' || CHR( 3 ) || CHR( 4 ) || CHR( 22 );
BEGIN
   RETURN TRANSLATE( in_text, v_search, 'a' );
END;
```